# IncompatibleRemoteServiceException after updating from GWT 2.7 to 2.8.1

Tags: java, serialization, gwt, deserialization, gwt-rpc

After updating my GWT 2.7 application to GWT 2.8.1 I receive the following exception: 
`com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.IncompatibleRemoteServiceException: The response could not be deserialized`

`Caused by: com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.SerializationException: /my/path/to/a/file.pdf`. This path is stored in the path variable of `MyClass`:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.IsSerializable;

public class MyClass implements IsSerializable {

    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String path;
    private List<String> assetClasses = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<String> keywords = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<Integer> regions = new ArrayList<>();

    public ReportLink() {
       // Empty default constructor for GWT serialization.
    }

    ...getters + setters following
}
```

As you can see I'm implementing `IsSerializable`. Moreover I have an empty constructor (which is probably the most popular reason for this exception ;-)) and the class is located in the shared folder (referenced in the *.gwt.xml).

I set the data like this from a database query:

```
myClass.setName(resultSet.getString("name"));
myClass.setPath(resultSet.getString("path"));
String keywords = resultSet.getString("keywords");
myClass.setKeywords(Arrays.asList(keywords.split("\\s*,\\s*")))
...
```

and add different `MyClass` to a `List<MyClass>`. Afterwards two of these lists are added to a map and returned:

```
Map<String, List<MyClass>> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("A", a);
map.put("B", b);
return map;
```

This is only happening on the server after compilation. In SuperDevMode everything works fine. Any idea?

I already deleted the classes and deploy folders, did a project + gwt-unit-cache clean and recompiled the project multiple times but the exception still occurs.

I'm also wondering why the exception explicitly logs the String `path` which should be serializable without problems?!

Comment: try to clear your browser cache maybe

Comment: I already did...no success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason was an old version of `gwt-servlet.jar` with another name in the `WEB-INF/lib` folder beside the new `gwt-servlet.jar` of version 2.8.1. Due to that it was not obvious on the first sight. Embarrassing, but perhaps it reminds others to double-check...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, just add Serializable to the enum (implement the interface) and add a constructor without parameters,  that's it...

Comment: Why does this solution work? Can you add a little explanation? Thanks!

Comment: As mentioned in the question the empty constructor and the implementation of IsSerializable was not the problem. The default constructor without arguments is needed for serialization purposes in GWT. A common issue that this is missing but in this case it was the existence of two gwt-servlet.jar as stated in the marked answer.